# checking if there is a folder with a name that start with a specific string

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script that is supposed to manage my running files. I want to make sure that the source and target folder exist before I run it and I can do this with `os.path.exists`. However, I have a set of foldernames `runner<i>`. Is there a way to check that there is some folders begining with that name?

For example, if in the path
`/path/to/runners`
I have at least one folder named `runner`:

> /path/to/runners/ $ ls 
>   file1.txt
>   file2.txt
>   folder1
>   folder2
>   runner1
>   runner35
>   zfolder

Then the result is true. Remove runner1 *and* runner35 and it will be false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import os
if any(x.startswith('runner') for x in os.listdir('/path/to/runners')):
    print "At least one entry begins with 'runner'"
```

That uses the helpful [`any` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Generator_expressions).

Comment: +1 for this. `glob` is useful if you actually want to use the list of matching paths but a quick non-rigorous test shows this method to be about twice as fast as glob

Answer (score 7):

Mark Longair's answer is quite fine, and an (equivalent) alternative for this kind of expression is to use glob:

```
import glob
if glob.glob('/path/to/runners/runner*'):
    print "At least one entry begins with 'runner'"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import glob

if glob.glob('/path/to/runners/runner*'):
    print 'condition satisfied'
```